# Does Ballerina regex replace support capture groups?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I want to escape `/` and `.` in a string.
Ex: for `foo/pets/1.2.3` the expected output is `foo\/pets\/1\.2\.3`

I tried the following:

```
regex:replaceAll("foo/pets/1.2.3", "(\\.|/)", "\\\\$1");
```

The output I'm getting is: `foo\\$1pets\\$11\\$12\\$13`

Is there a way to achieve the expected version?

Comment: Using capturing groups to do replacement is not supported by neither `regex` nor `regexp` libraries.

What you have to do is write two statements to escape `/` and `.` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lakshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13330552/lakshan-weerasinghe) mentioned, it seems capturing groups were not supported in the `regex` library, which has been [deprecated](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/regex/latest). However, I was able to get the expected outcome using the [`lang.regexp`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/latest#replaceAll) library instead using the following code:

```
import ballerina/lang.regexp;
import ballerina/io;

isolated function replaceFunction(regexp:Groups groups) returns string => "\\" + groups[0].substring();

public function main() {
    string str = "foo/pets/1.2.3";
    var result = re `([//\.])`.replaceAll(str, replaceFunction);
    io:println(result); // Output: "foo\/pets\/1\.2\.3"
}
```

Comment: lang.regexp is one of the [langlib modules](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/langlib-functions/) that _"is a library defined by the [Ballerina] language providing fundamental operations on built-in data types"_. So the current Ballerina version very much supports regular expression capturing groups. The previous implementation didn't.

Comment: Yes, the original wording of my answer was incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out. I have made an edit to better reflect this.